# Mongoose/Mongodb using $set vs just setting the values in update queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a difference, when updating a value in mongodb/mongoose between using `$set`:

```js
await Users.findOneAndUpdate({_id:"xxx"},{$set: {name:"Denis"} })
```

and just setting it like this:

```js
await Users.findOneAndUpdate({_id:"xxx"},{name:"Denis"})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update//), it mentioned that:

> By default, if you don't include any update operators in doc, Mongoose will wrap doc in `$set` for you. This prevents you from accidentally overwriting the document.

So there is no difference unless you specify `overwrite: true` in options.

Comment: this is when stackoverflow is still more useful than chatGPT ...